# Remove parts from string in python

Tags: python, string

So I have a few thousand strings in a format like this:

`"something - something else (another thing) [even more things]"`

And I need to remove the parenthesis and square brackets but my problem is that any other part of the string could contain square brackets/parenthesis too (there could also be more square brackets/parenthesis in the square brackets, but the parenthesis could only contain square brackets and not more parenthesis) and the number of spaces is also different for each string. The only thing that is constant is that the square brackets/parenthesis I want to remove are always at the end of the string. How would I remove these without changing anything else in the string to get the output string:

`"something - something else"`

Edit: Just to clarify the length of the string and the number of words can always be different, it's just always the same "shape", basically it's:

`"some unknown string" + "-" + "some unknown string" + "(some unknown string)" + "[some unknown string]"`

Comment: If the unknown string are arbitrary this is impossible to parse correctly without further information. E.g. if the first or the second string do contain a `-`, which one is the correct one? if the first string contain an unmatched `(` and a `-` before that, which one is the *correct* `(` to consider? In any case, it might be a good idea to look into `pyparsing`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need to be able to find and cut it at those brackets? Or is it a case of being able to simply slice away the end of the string? If so, you could do it using the slice method in python like so:

`

```
   str = "something - something else (another thing) [even more things]"
   str_to_cut = "something - something else"
     
    print ("Original string: " + str) 
    print(len(str_to_cut)) 
  
    # slicing string characters after position len 
    res_str = str[:21] 
       
     
    print ("String after removal of character: " + res_str)
```

`

Comment: I need to cut it specifically at those brackets but the problem is that there might be brackets somewhere else in the string or even in the brackets themselves which makes it not possible to simply search for the last `"("` and simply cut from there. The length of the string can be different and the number of words can also be different.

Answer (score 0):

If your input does not contain parenthesis inside your square brackets, you could just use [`rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) to find the position of the last `"("` occurring in the string. Then, slicing the initial string until that position (minus one to account for the space) will give you the desired output:

```py
s = "something - something else (another thing) [even more things]"
print(repr(s[:s.rfind("(") - 1]))
# 'something - something else'
```

Comment: This would work but only as long as the last square bracket doesn't contain another round bracket. Changing it to cut at the last `"("`before the first `"["` would also only work until there is a `"["` somewhere else in the string, and changing it to cut at the last `"("`before the last `"["` would also only work if there is no `"["` within the last square bracket.

Comment: @Ben0981 You did not mention in your question that the content inside the last square brackets could be a parenthesis. If that is the case, you need to parse your input in a more complex fashion (and perhaps also update the question).

Comment: I assumed the word brackets includes parenthesis, I'll update my question to include parenthesis.